# VBA: Prevent _Click Event from Triggering at Value Change

Tags: vba, excel, infinite-loop

I have been had this issue in mind for months and it remains unresolved after so much research. I'm working with Excel Checkboxes and trying to make the system foolproof whereas "if A & B cannot occur together, if A is clicked and you click B, then the macro unclicks A for you".

However, the issue I'm running into is that this starts (as shown in my code below) an infinite loop,

The first Sub:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxD11_Click()

    If CheckBoxD12.Value = True Then

        CheckBoxD12.Value = False
        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("D9").Interior.ColorIndex = 20

        CheckBoxD11.Value = True
        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("B8:E8").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End If

    TextBox1_Change
    TextBox2_Change

    If CheckBoxD11.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("B9:E9").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 221, 221)

        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("D8").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("B9:E9").Interior.ColorIndex = 20

        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("D8").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End If

End Sub
```

.. and the second Sub:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxD12_Click()

    If CheckBoxD11.Value = True Then
        CheckBoxD11.Value = False
        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("D8").Interior.ColorIndex = 2

        CheckBoxD12.Value = True
        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("B9:E9").Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    End If

    TextBox1_Change
    TextBox2_Change

    If CheckBoxD12.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("B8:E8").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 221, 221)

        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("D9").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("B8:E8").Interior.ColorIndex = 2

        Worksheets("Dynamic_Parking_Sheet").Range("D9").Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    End If

End Sub
```

I tried working a bit with public flags, but the issue persisted.

Any advice?

Thank you,
~Deut

Comment: Why don't you try to use radio button instead of checkbox?

Comment: or Disable/Enable events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want checkboxes to uncheck each other, try simplifying your code to something like this:

```
CheckBoxD12.Value = Not CheckBoxD11.value
```

It would work quite well and there should be no loops.
Or something like this, made simple:

```
Private Sub chb_A_Click()
    If chb_A Then chb_B = False
End Sub

Private Sub chb_B_Click()
    If chb_B Then chb_A = False
End Sub
```

The idea here is that it only checks for being checked to allow the option for both checkboxes to be unchecked.

Comment: I tried the first approach and it seems to work great; I still need to update the whole code. You're awesome!